# Proper acting when a process is consuming 100% time of CPU

Tags: java, perl, cpu-usage

On several machines I have a problem with a process that is using 100% time of a CPU.

`USER     PID  %CPU %MEM    VSZ    RSS  TT  STAT STARTED        TIME COMMAND`

`root   85740 100.0  0.2  34668   6352  ??  R    12:06AM   472:20.86 /usr/bin/javad (perl5.12.4)`

At this moment, this process is running almost for over 8 hours:

`# ps -p 85740 -o etime=`

`08:05:25`

`# ps -auxeww` shows full command as: `root   29323 99.0  0.2   32292   6692 ??  R    11:21PM   596:50.14 SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/bash LOGNAME=root MAIL=/var/mail/root PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/fgz/bin SUDO_GID=1004 OLDPWD=/usr/local PWD=/usr/local/jboss4/bin _=./start.sh TERM=xterm USER=root HOME=/root SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash SUDO_USER=fgz SUDO_UID=1004 USERNAME=root JBOSS_HOME=/usr/local/jboss4 SHLVL=1 /usr/bin/javad (perl5.12.4)`

On this particular machine we have JBoss AS installed (and also on others).

I would appreciate any hints how to source which starts this process. In `/etc/crontab` or `crontab -l` I don't have any actions that would start perl.

And what is interesting:

`# ls -al /usr/bin/javad`

`ls: /usr/bin/javad: No such file or directory`

While process is still running.

Other Java processes that are running:

`USER     PID  %CPU %MEM    VSZ    RSS  TT  STAT STARTED        TIME COMMAND`

`root    1322   0.0  0.0  14688   1344   0- I    24Jun13     0:00.00 /bin/sh ./run.sh -b 10.0.5.9`

`root    1334   0.0 11.8 2465148 493584   0- I    24Jun13    40:40.66 [java]`

Where `run.sh` is a JBoss Bootstrap Script.

Comment: The user running the command is `fgz`, would it be possible to ask them what they did?

Comment: Dump the stack of the Java process. There's a high probability it is stuck in a `while { ... }` loop with no valid exit condition. If you can repeatedly dump the stack and find it staying in the same routine then you can tell the developer they have a problem in that particular function.

Comment: @PP. is this a proper way to do it: "`kill -SIGQUIT process_id` will cause a core dump from a running process (assuming that resource limits allow it). Or see `man 3 abort` for causing a program to dump itself."? I would appreciate any hint how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see perl consuming 100% CPU on a machine running JBoss, I'm willing to bet that the machine has been infected by a worm.

Just this morning I also discovered a non-existent /usr/bin/javad running on a Linux box where JBoss AS is installed. Investigation revealed that there was a security hole - someone from Romania had accessed /invoker/JMXInvokerServlet and managed to deploy a 'web application' (yeah!) on the server. You should check if this 'invoker' is accessible on your server. If it is, the next question would be, is it really necessary? In my case I just removed it (by removing the $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/http-invoker.sar directory), restarted JBoss and verified that the web application is still running.

Answer (score 1):

Your errant process is the result of an old JBoss exploit:

https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/mjc/2011/10/20/statement-regarding-security-threat-to-jboss-application-server

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on monitoring Java processes: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things8/

The most useful tool is `jstack`. If it is installed on your system then use it to show what the busy process is doing. I should mention that `jstack` is a command-line tool. You use it along with the process ID of the busy Java process. It should give a stack dump of every thread in that process. Most threads *should* be waiting for a synchronisation object (indicating that they are not busy, not using any CPU).

Failing the existence of `jstack` you can send an appropriate signal to the process - but finding where the stack is dumped can be a challenge. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734696/how-to-get-stack-trace-of-a-thread for details.